# C# Nhibernate - Adding new item to many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, many-to-many, set

So i have the two tables (Product and Supplier) connected through a many-to-many relationship. They're coded as follows:

```
class Product
{
    public virtual uint id { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual float stock { get; set; }
    public virtual float value { get; set; }
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet saleItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet stockInlets { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
class Supplier
{
    public virtual uint id { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public virtual string addressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string addressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string telephone1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string telephone2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet products { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet stockInlets { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I mapped their relationship:

```
<set name="suppliers" table="product_x_supplier" fetch="join" lazy="false">
  <key column="product_id" />
  <many-to-many class="Supplier" column="supplier_id" />
</set>
```

-

```
<set name="products" table="product_x_supplier" fetch="join" lazy="false">
  <key column="supplier_id" />
  <many-to-many class="Product" column="product_id" />
</set>
```

Now, I'm having a problem when inserting a new Product and trying to link the correspondent Suppliers to it. I did manage to Update an already existing one, but not to create a new one. Here's the (simplified) code I'm trying to use:

```
Product p = new Product()
{
    name = "Test product",
    stock = 0,
    value = 2,
    category = (Category)cats[0]
};

for (int i = 0; i < suppliers.Length; i++)
{
    p.suppliers.Add(suppliers[i]);
}

repository.Add(p);
```

It tells me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. I tried to instantiate the object, doing something like `p.suppliers = new IList<Supplier>();` but then it complained it `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<TCC.Hibernate.Domain.Classes.Supplier>'`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 class Supplier
 {
      public Supplier()
      {
          this.suppliers = new HashedSet<Supplier>();
      }

      public virtual ICollection<Product> products { get; private set; }
 }
```

This way you will ensure that collection is always initialized and nobody can replace it.

Comment: A couple things are off here... a) The Supplier class shouldn't need a collection of itself and b) The `ISet` implementation class is `HashSet`, not `HashedSet`. The suggestion to initialize the property inside the default constructor is the correct way to do this. +1!

Comment: Thanks, I dunno how I didn't think of that before. @JesseWebb, HashedSet actually worked for me, while HashSet didn't.

Comment: The `HashedSet` class is a Spring.NET class (http://www.springframework.net/doc/sdk/2.0/html/Spring.Core~Spring.Collections.HashedSet.html) while the `HashSet` class is built-in to the .NET framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). I guess both would work if you have Spring in your list of references. I am not sure why `HashSet` didn't work for you, maybe missing a `using` statement?

Comment: Hashed is from Iesi.Collections

Answer (score 3):

Use...

```
p.suppliers = new List<Supplier>();
```

Your list needs to be initialized prior to adding items to it. `IList` is an interface, not a class, you need to use `List`, the default implementation of `IList`.

As an aside, it seems you may not be that familiar with the C# language or the built-in .NET libraries. I would suggest becoming more familiar with basic C# development before playing with third-party libraries like Hibernate. Hibernate is an especially complex library that will be the cause of many headaches for you if you have troubles diagnosing even simple errors like these.

Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I didn't notice that your field types were `ISet`, not `IList`. You will have to use an `ISet` implementation like `HashSet` or `SortedSet` as Sly has demonstrated in their answer.

You can browse the MSDN to learn more about these collection types...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sbxh9x2

Comment: That actually gave me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TCC.Hibernate.Domain.Classes.Supplier>' to 'Iesi.Collections.ISet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. And when I tried casting it, it didn't work either. But ye, I'm not that experienced with C#, but I'm doing my best.